# phpstorm unresolved function or method $()

Tags: phpstorm

I have the following problem: phpstorm do not recognize jquery methods and here and there I see

[image]

> Unresolved function or method $()

This was bugging me for sometime but finally I tried to get rid of it with **File->Settings->JavaScript->Libraries** and adding jquery as a global / project.

My library setup looks like this:[image]

But is has not changed anything. I still see those pesky notices. Does anyone know how to get rid of them?

Comment: Please show screenshot of your Library setup for jQuery.

Comment: OK .. so you are using jQuery v1.11. I do see the same behaviour when using **1.11.0** .. but **1.10.2 works just fine**. I think it has something to do with "AMD-fy jQuery source" -- http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14113 -- looks like IDE has some issues figuring out this style. If you wish (and can) -- roll back to v1.10.2 -- changes there are not so dramatic/critical.

Comment: Actual ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10908

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There is a really stupid workaround,

Download the Library (*in this case* **jQuery**) from inside the IDE itself.

- Open up settings (*Ctrl + Alt + S on Linux*)
- Navigate to **Languages & Frameworks** -> **Javascript** -> **Libraries**
- Click **Download** and choose **jQuery**

Hopefully the errors will vanish

**EDIT:**
After running the IDE through *Fiddler*, I realised this only solves the problem because of the version the IDE downloads.

So, the correct workaround is to Add older, non-AMD jQuery versions as a Global scoped Library and add the latest one as a Project scope library.

The latest non-AMD versions are:

**1.10.2** for 1.x series. And, **2.0.0** for 2.x series.

Comment: so stupid a workaround it almost feels like phpstorm devs wished for us to actually use that way...

Comment: As of PhpStorm 8, this is found in Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries

Comment: yeah well, they said pStorm 8.0.2 is supposed to have this issue solved already

Comment: Note that restarting the application may be needed.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue with version 1.11.2, and resolved it simply by adding the uncompressed version into my js folder.

Comment: Should've been the answer. I added the un-compressed jquery version right next to my compressed jquery min. Followed by immediately adding the uncompressed version to my .gitignore file, so my production always uses the min version.

Answer (score 7):

Just copy the uncompressed version of jQuery into your project folder.
you don't even need to import it into your project, just copy it to javascript folder.

Comment: You still have to alter the <script src="../../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> statement to have it recognized.

Comment: The Webstorm dependency management is not dependent on altering js files(which is both good and bad)
I think think the Phpstorm would be the same...

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery **v1.11.0** shows exactly the same behaviour here as well. At the same time previous version **1.10.2** works fine in IDE (no warnings).

I think it has something to do with "AMD-fy jQuery source" ticket (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14113) -- looks like IDE has some issues figuring out this style.

If you wish (and can) -- roll back to jQuery v1.10.2 (which is like half a year old, which means it's stable and still good to use).

Hopefully IDE will be able to properly parse this new jQuery style in next release.

---

Actual ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10908

Comment: This is NOT a solution. Importing jQuery from IDE worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you import both 1.11.0 and 1.10.2 in phpstorm it will be resolved

You don't have to rollback your project.

Comment: Hmm.. tried that (although it's 1.10.4 that I added - couldn't find 1.10.2) and it's still giving me the error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: anything after 1.10.2 will not work, thats the last, non-AMD version they released