# WebStorm highlights all $-operators as "unknown" in a jQuery project

Tags: javascript, jquery, webstorm

Maybe a newbie-question:

Why does my WebStorm IDE not recognize any jQuery code when on the other side the created page works well in the browser?

That's what I did:

- I've installed WebStorm Version 2018.2.6.
- Then I downloaded a simple jQuery demo project, this one:
  http://javascriptbook.com/code/c07/example.html (the html-file, the css file and the .cs file).
- Then I downloaded a minified jQuery, "jquery-3.3.1.min.js".
- I put all the files in a folder, changed the relative paths and updated the jQuery filename, so in the html file it reads "`<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> <script src="code.js"></script>`"

When I view that via WebStorm (=when I launch Chrome and WebStorm provides the webserver), then everything works perfectly. Animation is done just nicely.

However, in the WebStorm IDE all occurrences of the `$` operator in the .js file are marked as "unresolved function".

I found these articles:

- [phpstorm unresolved function or method $()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616683/phpstorm-unresolved-function-or-method)
- [I can't add jQuery to WebStorm, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401482/i-cant-add-jquery-to-webstorm-why)

So I went to `Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries` and download&installed "jquery". It's then listed as "@types/jquery".
However, the error highlighting is still there.

Do I need to make more source mofications or how do I get that working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types resolving won't work when using minified library version, but downloading typings (`@types/jquery`) should work:

[image]

make sure that the library is downloaded properly (can you see it in *External libraries* list in the **Project** tool window?); invalidating caches (*File | invalidaate caches, Invalidate and restart*) can also help

Comment: "...won't work when using minified..." - that line was the clue. I only need to copy the non-minified jQueryfile into the project folder, and all "bad" highlightings are gone. Thanks a lot!!